# nosetests web module cannot be found

Tags: python, nose

I am using python version 2.7.10 (the default python on my machine). I have a python module which I would like to test. The first (and only) import in the module is:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/hello', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The module is called `app.py` and resides under the `bin` directory of my project. I also have a `__init__.py` defined in this directory. I run the corresponding test module, called `app_tests.py` using nose, like so:

```
nosetests
```

and I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named web)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/dev/python/workspace/projects/gothonweb/tests/app_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bin.app import app
  File "/Users/dev/python/workspace/projects/gothonweb/bin/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import web
ImportError: No module named web

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea why this is happening as I can run and execute `app.py` without any issues.

I run the `nosetests` command from my project root. The project structure looks like so:

```
devs-MacBook-Pro:gothonweb dev$ ls -R
bin     docs        gothonweb   setup.py    templates   tests

./bin:
__init__.py __init__.pyc    app.py      app.pyc

./docs:

./gothonweb:
__init__.py __init__.pyc

./templates:
hello_form.html index.html  layout.html

./tests:
__init__.py     app_tests.py        gothonweb_tests.py  tools.py
__init__.pyc        app_tests.pyc       gothonweb_tests.pyc tools.pyc
```

I am using the system python in `/usr/bin/python` because I have some vim plugins which won't work if I use the python I installed with brew. I did link the python installed via brew (under `/usr/local/bin/python`, version 2.7.13) and tried that instead, but I get the same error, saying `web` cannot be found. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: N.B. `bin` is a strange name for a package.  There most probably shouldn't be an `__init__.py` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you got this error

> ImportError: No module named web

That means you haven't a module, You must install it or have it in your project directory (Actually project `PATH`)

You need to install `python-webpy`

```
sudo apt-get install  python-webpy
```

or install it with `pip`:

```
sudo pip install web.py
```

Read [this](http://webpy.org/install) manual.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I can run the code and test manually without any issues?

Comment: This fixed the problem. I had lpthweb.py installed. That doesn't seem to include web.py? Anyway it's working now. Thanks.